# Connecting to Heroku via Socket.io leads to timeout

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, sockets, heroku, socket.io

I deployed a SpringBoot REST API application written in Kotlin to Heroku. In this application I also implemented Socket.io, so a Socket.io server is running at port 8085. Locally, I can connect with an Socket.io request in Postman to the application socket. But when deploying, it leads to a timeout. No error logs, no info logs.

Does anyone have a solution for it? I attached the logs from the application on Heroku and the screenshots from Postman.

Thank you!

```
info Apr 12 08:48:13 chatty-bff app/web.1 Create a Procfile to customize the command used to run this process: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
info Apr 12 08:48:13 chatty-bff app/web.1 Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
info Apr 12 08:48:13 chatty-bff app/web.1 Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -XX:CICompilerCount=2 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1   .   ____          _            __ _ _
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1  :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.7.0)
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:14.130  INFO 2 --- [           main] com.ebucelik.chatty.ChattyApplicationKt  : Starting ChattyApplicationKt v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_362 on 134f4659-f4c6-442c-a874-e8ead56daee4 with PID 2 (/app/target/ChattyBackend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by u21476 in /app)
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:14.135  INFO 2 --- [           main] com.ebucelik.chatty.ChattyApplicationKt  : The following 1 profile is active: "prod"
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:14.074  INFO 2 --- [ionShutdownHook] c.c.socketio.SocketIOServer              : SocketIO server stopped
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:14.085  INFO 2 --- [ionShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:14.094  INFO 2 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
info Apr 12 08:48:14 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:14.115  INFO 2 --- [ionShutdownHook] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
info Apr 12 08:48:15 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:15.097  INFO 2 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
info Apr 12 08:48:15 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:15.181  INFO 2 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 76 ms. Found 6 JPA repository interfaces.
info Apr 12 08:48:16 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:15.736  INFO 2 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 35601 (http)
info Apr 12 08:48:16 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:15.748  INFO 2 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
info Apr 12 08:48:16 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:15.748  INFO 2 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.63]
info Apr 12 08:48:16 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:15.811  INFO 2 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
info Apr 12 08:48:16 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:15.811  INFO 2 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1613 ms
info Apr 12 08:48:16 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:15.966  INFO 2 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
info Apr 12 08:48:16 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:16.052  INFO 2 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.9.Final
info Apr 12 08:48:16 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:16.190  INFO 2 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
info Apr 12 08:48:16 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:16.300  INFO 2 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
info Apr 12 08:48:16 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:16.538  INFO 2 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
info Apr 12 08:48:16 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:16.555  INFO 2 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL81Dialect
info Apr 12 08:48:17 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:17.040  INFO 2 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
info Apr 12 08:48:17 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:17.048  INFO 2 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
info Apr 12 08:48:18 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:18.167  INFO 2 --- [           main] c.c.socketio.SocketIOServer              : Session store / pubsub factory used: MemoryStoreFactory (local session store only)
info Apr 12 08:48:18 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:18.356  INFO 2 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-1] c.c.socketio.SocketIOServer              : SocketIO server started at port: 8085
info Apr 12 08:48:18 app app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:18.390  WARN 2 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
info Apr 12 08:48:19 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:18.681  INFO 2 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 35601 (http) with context path ''
info Apr 12 08:48:19 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:48:18.687  INFO 2 --- [           main] com.ebucelik.chatty.ChattyApplicationKt  : Started ChattyApplicationKt in 5.034 seconds (JVM running for 5.45)
info Apr 12 08:51:17 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:51:16.762  INFO 2 --- [io-35601-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
info Apr 12 08:51:17 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:51:16.762  INFO 2 --- [io-35601-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
info Apr 12 08:51:17 chatty-bff app/web.1 2023-04-12 15:51:16.764  INFO 2 --- [io-35601-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
```

[image]

I tried, to change the ports to the same port as the REST API application but still not working.